# Run time Error 3075 - missing Operator - VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub BeforeUpdate

    Dim No_Map As Integer
    Dim SysDate As Date

    SysDate = Now()

    Debug.Print "Date is " & SysDate
    strSQL1 = "UPDATE MaponDemand SET SysDate = " & SysDate & " WHERE No_Map = " & _ No_Map.Value
    db.Execute strSQL1, dbFailOnError Or dbSeeChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `Private Sub BeforeUpdate(Cancel as Integer)` i think... also there is an extra `_` before & `No_Map.Value` and I am not sure you can use an `or` operator with `dbFailOnError Or dbSeeChanges`...

Comment: .. and No_Map is declared as Integer. So No_Map.Value will fail..
.. and No_Map is not initialized with any value ..
.. and depending to database backend you have to quote a date value

Answer (score 0):

The date won't be automatically converted into a date which SQL can handle.

Try
`strSQL1 = "UPDATE MaponDemand SET SysDate = #" & SysDate & "# WHERE No_Map = " & _ No_Map.Value` (hashtags **#** around the date).